# jQuery UI DropShadow - How to put drop shadow around div

Tags: jquery-ui

I need to know how to get a drop shadow like the date picker in this link

http://taitems.github.com/Aristo-jQuery-UI-Theme/

Is there a default class I need to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSS:

```
.ui-datepicker {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that if you are running ie9, that compatibility mode is turned off, or you will not see the shadow.
Cost me an hour.